# Adding missing rows with a join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL script that returns this derived table.

```
MM/YYYY  Cat    Score
02/2012  Test1  19
04/2012  Test1  15
05/2012  Test1  16
07/2012  Test1  14
08/2012  Test1  15
09/2012  Test1  15
12/2012  Test1  11
02/2012  Test2  15
03/2012  Test2  13
05/2012  Test2  18
06/2012  Test2  14
08/2012  Test2  15
09/2012  Test2  14
12/2012  Test2  10
```

As you can see, I am missing some MM/YYYYs (03/2012, 06/2012, 11/2012, etc).

I would like to fill in the missing MM/YYYYs with the Cat & a 0 (zero) form the score.  I know what the beginning date (1/2012) should be.

I have tried to join a table that contains the all MM/YYYY for the ranges the query will be run, but this only returns the missing rows for the first occurrence, it does not repeat for each Cat (should have known that).

So my question is this, can I do this using a join or will I have to do this in a temp table, and then output the data.  I am looking to return a table, that has 24 rows, for the date range 1/2012 to 12/2012, with the appropriate Cat (Test1 & Test2) & the corresponding score, if it exists or a zero if it was not in the origial table.

AHIGA, LarryR…

Comment: How did you join your table with all dates?

Comment: do you have separate category table? can you post all tables used in your query to return results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can use some CTEs to get what you are after.  This uses three CTEs:  One for all the dates, one for your categories, then a third to cross join them.  The third is really redundant but it's just to make it a little more obvious what we are looking at.

```
DECLARE 
     @StartDate datetime = '2/1/2012'
    ,@EndDate datetime = '4/26/2013'
;WITH DATES AS 
(
    SELECT
        CAST(MONTH(@StartDate) as varchar(20)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) as varchar(20)) 'CurrMonth'
       ,@StartDate as Datefield
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       CAST(MONTH(CurrDate) as varchar(20)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(CurrDate) as varchar(20))
       ,CurrDate
    FROM
       DATES
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, Datefield)) CxA(CurrDate)
    WHERE CurrDate < @EndDate
)
,CATS AS
(
    SELECT 'Test1' as 'Cat'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Test2'
)
,AllTheThings AS
(
    SELECT
        Datefield
       ,CurrMonth
       ,Cat
    FROM
       DATES D
    CROSS JOIN 
       CATS C
)

SELECT * FROM AllTheThings
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understodd correctly, you would join your table like this

```
SELECT 
  d.Date,c.Cat,ISNULL(t.Score,0) As Score
FROM YourDateTable d
CROSS JOIN
 ( -- Your Cat Table or UNION Cat here
   SELECT 'Test1' AS Cat 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Test2' 
 ) c
LEFT JOIN YourCurrentTable t
  ON t.Date = d.Date
  AND t.Cat = c.Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a date table (over a temp table). It takes very little space.

Comment: When the date table is joined, only one occurance of the missing dates are joined and the Cat is NULL.

Comment: If I join the date table, the missing dates will appear only once and the Cat col will be NULL.

Comment: @larryr You fill them based on whatever you want them to be.

Comment: @larryr see my answer for an example of how you can do what FreshPrince is talking about